# Why are only four numbers recognized in NumberFormat?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have the following problem, when I enter a value in my TextField, which is embedded in NumberFormat. Then only three numbers are accepted and then the field is reset. I want to divide my value in my textfield by a format, this is determined by the drop down menu. So if I select the value thousand then the value in the text field should be calculated by 1000. But as soon as I divide the value in the text field by the number, from the drop down menu, then I can only enter three numbers....
How to solve this problem, unfortunately I have no approach at all?

Example Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-babbage-vrhfx?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Reason it is resetting after 3 digits is: `"1"/1` is 1. `"11"/1` is 11, `"111"/1` is 111 BUT `"1,111"/1` is `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

In your code value is a string, so as @Ajeet Shah has reported `"1,111"/1` is `NaN`, a possible workaround could be:

```
<Controller
    name="test"
    control={control}
    render={({ onChange, value }) => {
      let valueInt = parseInt(value?.replaceAll(",", ""), 10);
      return (
        <NumberFormat
          thousandSeparator=","
          value={valueInt / format}
          onChange={onChange}
          customInput={TextFieldCustom}
          placeholder="test"
          decimalSeparator="."
          label="test"
          variant="outlined"
        />
      );
    }}
    fixedDecimalScale
  />
```

To remove all ',' and convert the string into an integer then make the operation

Code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-knuth-omy9b?file=/src/App.tsx:780-1348